# Intermittent PostgreSQL connection failures with Npgsql and integrated security: "Either the target name is incorrect or..."

Tags: asp.net, postgresql, windows-authentication, npgsql, amazon-aurora

I am seeing occasional database connection failures. When it occurs, all database connections will fail until I stop/start the IIS application pool (recycling the app pool is not sufficient). After I stop/start the IIS application pool, everything works fine. The problem occurs very sporadically - maybe ten times in the past month. The problem is specific to an application: while an application is down, other applications on the same server (different app pool) can still access the same database via the same method. I cannot reproduce the problem.

The error message is "Either the target name is incorrect or the server has rejected the client credentials." I see a handful of other questions that mention this error message, but they are not duplicates, because (1) my issue is intermittent and (2) I am not using WCF.

I am fairly confident the problem is a combination of PostgreSQL and integrated security. I don't see this problem on PostgreSQL deployments without integrated security, and I don't see this problem on SQL Server deployments with integrated security.

Any idea what might be causing this problem, or how I can reproduce it?

**Relevant Tech Stack**

- C# / ASP.NET / .NET Framework
- IIS
- Windows Server (EC2)
- Aurora PostgreSQL (RDS)
- [Npgsql](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Npgsql/)

**Connection String (from web.config)**

Note we are using [integrated security](https://www.npgsql.org/doc/security.html#integrated-security-gsssspikerberos).

```
<add name="PostgreSqlConnectionString" connectionString="Server=REDACTED;Port=REDACTED;Database=REDACTED;Integrated Security=True;Username=REDACTED;"/>
```

**Stack Trace**

```
Either the target name is incorrect or the server has rejected the client credentials.:    at System.Net.Security.NegoState.StartSendAuthResetSignal(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult, Byte[] message, Exception exception)
   at System.Net.Security.NegoState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] message, LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Net.Security.NegoState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] message, LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Net.Security.NegoState.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Net.Security.NegotiateStream.AuthenticateAsClient(NetworkCredential credential, String targetName)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.<AuthenticateGSS>d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.<Authenticate>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.<Open>d__149.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Npgsql.ConnectorPool.<AllocateLong>d__20.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.<>c__DisplayClass32_0.<<Open>g__OpenLong|0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.Open()
```

**Update**

I discovered this error in the postgresql logs. It appears to be strongly correlated with the connection failures.

Example #1:

```
FATAL:  accepting GSS security context failed
DETAIL:  Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information: Key table entry not found
```

Example #2:

```
FATAL:  accepting GSS security context failed
DETAIL:  Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information: Request ticket server [REDACTED] not found in keytab
```

Example #3:

```
FATAL:  accepting GSS security context failed
DETAIL:  Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information: Request ticket server [REDACTED] kvno 19 not found in
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at your connection pooling settings and make sure you close and dispose of the connection. I had seemed the same when the frameworks fail to open a connection, to me, this looks like the error is not related to the settings but more like "catch all" when the connection fails.

Can you share some code?

Comment: How would you suggest I try to reproduce this scenario?

Comment: I ran a test by opening a bunch of connections without closing/disposing them. I got a different error: "The connection pool has been exhausted." So I don't think this is the problem, at least by itself. Unless you have another idea?

Comment: can you share the code without the credentials so we can see what you do?

Comment: I can't really share the code as-is, because it's rather spread out with abstractions that aren't important for this question. It's mostly boilerplate ADO.NET code. The one notable exception is there is some logic for reusing connections. So if you open five connections, you might just get one connection that is reused. If you dispose a connection, it might not actually be disposed until later. So I wouldn't be surprised if there were some bug that leaves a connection open/undisposed. But even if we assume that is the root cause, how can I reproduce the issue?

Comment: connections are held by the framework and re-used rather than removed from memory using pooling at the driver level based on the checksum of the connection, however, there are 100 things that can go wrong at the DNS level or the failover at the Aurora db cluster. do you have access to the logs at the receiving databases, could be you fail-over to a secondary note witch "doesn't know you"